# cant position 2 Canvas correctly

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

i will keep it short, i got 2 canvases which i want to look like this

[image]

currently the second canvas is just stacking on the top left of the other, what am i doing wrong.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Family Photos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
</head>
<body>

<section>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>
</section>

<section>
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>
    
</section>

<section>
    <button onclick="saveasimage();"> Save Image </button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="remove();"> Delete </button>
</section>

<section>
    <script> window.onload = main(); </script>
</section>

<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    cursor:crosshair;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for giving the canvases position: absolute?

Comment: Your canvases are stacked on top of each other as they are both positioned absolutely with a top of 80px, the left will default to 0. Remove the absolute positioning and place your button section and smaller canvas in a flex row container.

Answer (score 0):

You have no styling for the rest of the elements, you want to put them in a flex-container and position everything in it.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

That is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the ***absolute*** positioning on both your *canvas* as this is placing both the canvas on top of each other. The absolute positioning is not needed.

You can reorder the sections in the order you wish them to layout on the page. Then wrap the ***buttons*** *section* and **smaller canvas** in a **div** and apply a [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) display to that element. This will place both the buttons section and canvas in a row. Naturally the other canvas will be below the div in your layout and positioned as you want it.

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#flex-cont {
  display: flex;
}

#flex-cont section:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#flex-cont section:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-left: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Family Photos</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="flex-cont">
    <section>
      <button onclick="saveasimage();"> Save Image </button>
      <br>
      <button onclick="remove();"> Delete </button>
    </section>
    <section>
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>

    </section>
  </div>
  <section>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>
  </section>



  <section>
  </section>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example of your desired layout using display [**grid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

You do not have to worry so much about the layout of the HTLM in terms of how it will render on the page as you can use the ***grid-template-areas*** and **grid-areas** CSS rules to reorder the elements where you want them to layout using ***grid-template-areas***. Note the use of *grid-areas* on each unique element as well.

```
  grid-template-areas: 
    "buttons small-canvas" 
    "buttons small-canvas" 
    "big-canvas big-canvas"
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#main {
  padding: .5rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "buttons small-canvas" 
    "buttons small-canvas" 
    "big-canvas big-canvas"
}

.buttons {
  grid-area: buttons;
}

.small-canvas {
  grid-area: small-canvas;
}

.big-canvas {
  grid-area: big-canvas;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Family Photos</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <section class="big-canvas">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>
    </section>

    <section class="small-canvas">
      <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="200">
        Your browser doesn't recognize the canvas element
    </canvas>

    </section>

    <section class="buttons">
      <button onclick="saveasimage();"> Save Image </button>
      <br>
      <button onclick="remove();"> Delete </button>
    </section>

    <section>
      <script>
        //window.onload = main();
      </script>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```